# Видео - хостинг с CDN

Tags: видео, cdn

Товарищи, очень нужен совет.
Необходимо залить тянуть на сайте видео в 600мб.
Просто грузить его с хоста очень медленно.
Выбрали вимео, он дает все что надо, только за 19к в год.
Вопрос, есть ли атльтернативы.

ВК, ЮТУЮ, РУТУБ пробовали, не то, они не дают direct link на файл, что бы использовать его в

Answer (score 0):

Да, разумеется и самая подходящая для тебя - [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/?nc2=h_lg), там дают год бесплатного использования. Но, с по месячным ограничением 50 гб места и что - то ещё, при регистрации тебе придётся ввести данные карточки на случай, если ты привысишь ограничения для [бесплатного аккаунта](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/free/).